# Sage Murano api

Tags: sage-erp

Does anyone know if sage murano has an api? I've been 1 hour searching for documentation about sage murano api or webservice and I didn't find anything.

I know sage one does have an api to access from external code but it is possible that sage murano doesn't?

Thanks you,

Comment: It's impossible to find any documentation about Sage Murano on the internet. I've been trying to find something about Its programming language for a long time with no luck. It seems like the only way is to pay for a training or something.

Answer (score 0):

here you are. I don't know if this has been posted recently but we were looking for it just today.

https://developer.columbus.sage.com/docs/services/api/es

Enjoy!